# Elastic Beanstalk command line keeps changing optionsettings file

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to set

```
SecurityGroups=security_group
```

inside my *.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.environment* file, but everytime I run either **eb start** or **eb stop** the setting is removed.

The only point where it works is when I add the setting, and run **eb update**, but why on earth does my settings file get changed otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

For an explanation of this behaviour, please see [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=395052#395052) thread.

If you want to set environment variables, I suggest you do so though .config files in your .ebextensions folder. Please start [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

`ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.4/eb/linux/python2.7/scli/const.py` has the following already defined:

```
LocalOptionSettings = {                                                                                                           
u'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration' : {                                                                                    
    u'EC2KeyName',                                                                                                            
    u'InstanceType',-                                                                                                                                                                                 
},
```

If you put other properties in your `aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration` Resource, it will get removed automatically by eb. I wonder if this is by design.